# Spring Controller request parameter wrong encoding in one instance of Tomcat but not the others

Tags: spring, tomcat, utf-8, controller, http-request-parameters

I have a Spring MVC application which works fine in eclipse (local tomcat instance) and in a test environment where tomcat is installed as a service. But when I deploy the application in production the request parameters are not parsed correctly (Greek characters).

My server.xml configuration file in production (and in both local and test envirnonments) has the URIEncoding="utf-8" attribute on all connector elements.

I have set the CharacterEncodingFilter in web.xml.

My Jsp pages have all the

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

and

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

What else could be different between these Tomcat instances?

The only thing I can think off is the regional settings on windows but I hope this does not affect this?

Comment: do you send UTF characters in the URL or on the POST body?

Comment: hmm, it's a POST but the specific parameters are set on the URL (I know it's strange but it is a jquery plugin that does the request, so I am not sure if I can change this). But why would that matter, it works in two out of three of my Tomcat instances

Comment: so after your comment I was able to change my code and now the parameters are in the POST body. Still the same issue only in one particular instance of Tomcat. This is going to drive me mad.

Comment: is server.xml and config.xml the same?

Comment: server.xml is untouched from the default installation excepted that I added the URIEncoding part (in all Tomcat instances). What is config.xml?

Comment: Are the Tomcat instances the same version? And are the versions of Java installed on each server the same version?